# Julia in WSL does not open Jupyter notebook

Tags: ubuntu, julia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

using wsl I cannot open jupyter notebook. I write

```
julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook()
```

and`then this text appear and just nothing else happens

```
[ Info: running `/home/username/.local/bin/jupyter notebook`
```

does anyone know what could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I would try to solve it using SSH port forwarding (the `-L` option) as in https://medium.com/@gilad215/ssh-into-a-wsl2-host-remotely-and-reliabley-578a12c91a2   However I do not use WSL so cannot write you a full manual.

Answer (score 0):

WSL is somewhat "isolated", it will try to open the "browser" inside WSL, but WSL by default doesn't have a graphical interface, so it just opens the server but not the browser for you.

This is not a Julia problem, see general solution such as: https://harshityadav95.medium.com/jupyter-notebook-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-8b46fdf0a536